# Pass a table's colnames to an R block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, ess, r

I have an org file with this content:

```
#+name: my-table
| *Type*  | *Value* |
|---------+---------|
| Web     |     744 |
| Checks  |     520 |
| Cash    |     105 |
|---------+---------|
| *Total* |    1369 |
#+TBLFM: @5$2=vsum(@I..@II)
```

I would like to add an R script to draw a bar chart of the result so I tried:

```
#+NAME: barchart
#+begin_src R :results output graphics file :colnames yes :session :exports none :var data=my-table[0:-2] :file my-table.png
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = data) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = X.Type., y = X.Value.), stat = "identity")
#+end_src
```

This results in:

[image]

I like the result except the "X.Value." and "X.Type." to label each axis.

1. Is what I'm doing the standard way to pass a table with column names
   to R?
2. Is the R script written appropriately?
3. Is there a way to use my column names (i.e., "Type" and "Value") instead of "X.Value." and "X.Type."? Alternatively, can I change the axis label in R?

Comment: These are R questions, much more than emacs/Org mode questions. An R expert might stumble on it here, but you might have better luck asking it on SO.

Comment: yes and now. The way org-mode passes columns names or not to R is very specific to Org I guess. But I will search R documentation to workaround the issue if no one answers here.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from an interaction between R and org syntax. The strings `*Type*` and `*Value*` are fine for org mode columns, but are invalid object names (or column names) in R. Consequently, when you pass them to R, the leading `*` is converted to `X.`, and the trailing `*` is converted to `.`.

You can fix this by removing the asterixes (asterii?) from your table:

```
#+name: my-table
| Type    | Value   |
|---------+---------|
| Web     |     744 |
| Checks  |     520 |
| Cash    |     105 |
|---------+---------|
| Total   |    1369 |
#+TBLFM: @5$2=vsum(@I..@II)
```

And then changing the column names in your `aes()` directive to match:

```
#+NAME: barchart
#+begin_src R :results output graphics file :colnames yes :session :exports none :var data=my-table[0:-2] :file my-table.png
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = data) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Type, y = Value), stat = "identity")
#+end_src
```

This produces the following figure:

[image]